# How to use only certain number of rows per category for calculation?

Tags: tableau-api

I do a simple project where I calculate how many times a ball in casino roulette game lands in each pocket after after 20000 spins.

I have data for 2 different roulette tables with approx 10k spin results for each. I count a number of occurrences of each result which is fine.
The problem arises when I want to limit the calculation to lets say 5k results (rows of data) for each category (Roulette name in this case) and see how many times the ball land in each pocket after 5k spins.

How do I limit how many rows of data per each category do I pass to COUNT() function?
[Example of my wb as an img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEFVS.png)

Comment: Looking at your image, is the current sum of `cnt(result)` equal to 10000 and you want that to equal 5000?

Comment: Yes pretty much. But ive tried filtering with the calculated field like ‘if total(count(result)) <= [my_parameter] then “show”’. And it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You will have to add a `pk` field for each of your results so your pk will be 1-10000 or however many records you have.

**Parameter Setup:**

[image: parameter setup]

Choose `pk` from the `Set From Field` options

Create a calculated field named `N Results`

**`N Results`:**

`IF (pk - 1) < [View for N Results] THEN [result] END`

Add `N Results` to your filter shelf and `Exclude` `NULL`. Show `View for N Results` parameter and type in a value. Your grand total should now equal the parameter value.

**Final Layout:**

[image: final]

Let me know how that turns out.

Comment: Yes it work indeed. Although, I have no access to manipulate with db to add a proper primary key. But It works this way and its great. Thanks